# Ошибка. linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, unix

Скачал игру портал 2 на убунту сделал все как на сайте было написано ,но выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что мне делать помогите плиз)
(я новичок)

Comment: Текстовую инфу лучше выкладывать в виде текста. Исправь пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша версия Ubuntu?
в терминале lsb_release -a
В ubuntu focal и groovy architecture determine which 32-bit packages

Steam использует i386 architecture
В терминале
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
Ваши пакеты, которых не хватает (libuuid.so.1 libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4)
sudo apt install libtcmalloc-minimal4:i386 libuuid1:i386

Для нахождения недостающих компонентов заходите на https://packages.ubuntu.com/ и в поисковике делаете запрос[image: Запрос] [image: Результат]